# what is the role=" " attribute for Literals in html5?

Tags: html, asp.net

I need to add the role attribute in the below line... `<asp:Literal ID="empID" runat="server" ></asp:Literal>`

Can anyone help me please..

Answer (score 0):

Literals don't have their own element, so cannot have any attributes.

Comment: Thank You..... basically I am trying to resolve this  issue  "Based on the "success criteria" for this test, the main body content area "Start Date*:" and the "Employee ID / Name / Enterprise ID" input text field should have a default accValue and they do not have a CurrentAriaRole assigned to them."...……..Can you give me any idea